# How to use JFrog cli in cake script

Tags: jfrog-cli, cakebuild

We are using cake script as part of our build process. Please let me know how can I use JFrog cli command in cake script.

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI

jf rt u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any of the `Command` (https://cakebuild.net/dsl/command/) or `StartProcess` (https://cakebuild.net/dsl/process/) aliases.
`Command` aliases make use of [Tool resolution](https://cakebuild.net/docs/writing-builds/tools/tool-resolution) provided by Cake.

For example:

```
Command(
    new []{ "jf", "jf.exe"},
    "rt u"
);
```

See also this blog post for more examples: https://cakebuild.net/blog/2022/10/cake-v2.3.0-released#command-aliases

If the tool is not available on the machine Cake provides some ways to install tools. See [Installing Tools](https://cakebuild.net/docs/writing-builds/tools/installing-tools) for details.